# Comparing Two Stored Procedures

Tags: mysql, sql-server

A beginner to SQL and I have been asked to prove that two SQL Stored Procs don't return the same data.

I have run both queries and copied both reports into an Excel file and used a VLOOKUP to show where id's are in one report and not another.

One Stored proc is much longer joining with other tables and to another database.
The other is a simple select from a table in the database.

I was told to go though the procs piece by piece and analyse the differences and then put together a report on why these procs don't return the same data.

Can anybody offer me any advice on what way you would do to create this report.

Comment: As i understand, you want to compare returned rows from two procedures? Is there is any key on that data sets that you can use to compare theme?

Comment: Yes trn_id is on both which i used the VLOOKUP on in Excel to show where id's are appearing in one proc but not in the other.

Comment: You can execute procedures into tables and then selec data from that tables with use UNION statement. UNION gives you distinct record list from two tables

Comment: I don't need to use parameters so could I take the main select from both queries and put both of those into a temp table. Then use a union on both temp tables. Would this work?

Comment: What is the background to this? Is your task to prove the results are different? One counterexample is already enough. Is your task to learn sql or the data or fix or modify the procs later? Then you should try to go though the procs piece by piece and understand what the procedures are doing in detail. Is your task to explain to your bosses what the procs are doing (in general)? Then you should try to go though the procs piece by piece and understand what the procedures are doing in detail. The report can be a 4 page summary or 2 sentences plus example depending on what is expected of you.

Comment: I was told that somebody thinks these reports are the same I thought my VLOOKUP would b enough but I was told I needed a detailed report so I presume i also need to probably go through the procs piece by piece.

Comment: You can write one query with two selects and union. In this case you don't need temp tables. You can create view and put your two tables select into.

Comment: *I was told to go though the procs piece by piece*  That implies understanding the way the results are obtained, the logic of the code.  Step through it with your eyeballs and explain the differences.  I'm not sure this is a question we can help you with.  Also, this cannot be both `mysql` and (Microsoft) `sql-server`.  Which is it?

Comment: Sorry Michael meant to tag just sql_server the best thing is for me to go through it as you suggested thanks